# Word to describe a relationship that fluctuates between being good and bad

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word to describe the dynamics of a relationship that oscillates between being loving/harmonious and toxic.

By relationship, I’m primarily referring to a romantic relationship between a couple, however it can also apply to any (romantic, familial or platonic )relationship.

*I hope my question makes sense. Grammar savants feel free to edit my post.*

Comment: Do you want a noun? an adjective? *"a word that describes"* could be either.

Comment: A see-saw relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**up-and-down** (or up and down) relationship

**mercurial** relationship

[image]
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=up+and+down+relationship%2Cmercurial+relationship&year_start=1945&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure if this qualifies as a "single word", I can't believe nobody has suggested ***[love-hate relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love%E2%80%93hate_relationship)*** yet, which has [all sorts of rich metaphorical usages](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/110566#eid38908869) beyond sexual relationships.

Wiki also links to ***[on-again, off-again relationship,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-again,_off-again_relationship)*** which is [typically but not exclusively used](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/on-again-off-again) in a romantic context.

And for Japanophiles, ***[tsundere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere)*** describes a [similar dynamic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsundere#Adjective)/[perennial trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Tsundere) of teen romance stories, which has been enjoying [a steady rise in usage since the turn of the millennium](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tsundere&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctsundere%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctsundere%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

Such a relationship can be termed ***bittersweet***.

M-W:

> ***[bittersweet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bittersweet)*** *adjective*
> Definition of bittersweet (Entry 2 of 2)
>
> 1: being at once bitter and sweet
> *especially* : pleasant but including or marked by elements of suffering or regret
> a bittersweet ballad
> bittersweet memories

Comment: Had this been posted as an answer on the day I would have selected this as the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

**frenemy**

*noun*

Informal. a person or group that is friendly toward another because the relationship brings benefits, but harbors feelings of resentment or rivalry:
Clearly, turning the competition into frenemies is good for your business.

source https://www.dictionary.com/browse/frenemy

Answer (score 0):

**"an unstable relationship"**

> - "liable to change or alteration, an unstable economy, unstable weather." [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unstable)
> - "disposed to temperamental, emotional, or psychological variability." [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unstable#:%7E:text=adj.-,1.,quickly%3A%20an%20unstable%20weather%20pattern.)

You could also use "unsteady" or "shaky".

Answer (score 0):

Hot and cold.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTHNpusq654&ab_channel=KatyPerryVEVO

'Cause you're hot then you're cold
You're yes then you're no
You're in then you're out
You're up then you're down
You're wrong when it's right
It's black and it's white
We fight, we break up
We kiss, we make up
(You) You don't really want to stay, no
(You) But you don't really want to go-o
You're hot then you're cold
You're yes then you're no
You're in then you're out
You're up then you're down

Answer (score 0):

**Volatile** !
Example given in [Definition](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/volatile):

> If you and your best friend have a volatile relationship, you frequently fight and make up.
>
> Volatile from Latin volatilis, "fleeting, transitory," always gives the sense of sudden, radical change. Think of it as the opposite of *stable*.